# After deleting item List View not updating/refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am using listview in Update panel. When i try to delete its deleting record from datatable but listview not updating. Bellow my button code inside in listview:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
<asp:ListView ID="lvSelectedVoucher" OnItemCommand="lvSelectedVoucher_OnItemCommand" OnLayoutCreated="lvSelectedVoucher_LayoutCreated" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="text-left" colspan="2">
                    <div id="mvRemoveSelectedId1" class="mv-action" title="Remove item" onclick="removeVoucher">                            
                            <asp:ImageButton class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" ID="imgDelete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Voucher?')"
                                    runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex +1%>'  CommandName="Delete" />
                        </div>
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltlMerchant"  Text='<%# Eval("MerchantName") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Literal>                        
                    </td>
```

My server side code bellow:

```
 protected void lvSelectedVoucher_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                int listcount = lvSelectedVoucher.Items.Count;

                if (listcount - 1 == index)
                {
                    DataTable curTable = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedVoucher"];
                    curTable.Rows[index].Delete();
                    ViewState.Add("SelectedVoucher", curTable);
                    lvSelectedVoucher.DataSource = null;
                    lvSelectedVoucher.DataSource = curTable;
                    lvSelectedVoucher.DataBind();
                    UpdatePanel1.Update();
                }
       }
 }
```

How can I refresh my listview after delete one record ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please add more markup of your page (UpdatePanel and ListView)?

Comment: **Hind:** Make sure that you have set **IsPostBack** check on pageload

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            VoucherInventoryListView();
        }
}

Comment: What are your update panel's triggers?

Comment: I am not using triggers because i am deleting OnItemCommand event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have using my inside ItemDeleting event & ListView refreshing properly

```
     protected void lvSelectedVoucher_ItemDeleting(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
 if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                int listcount = lvSelectedVoucher.Items.Count;

                if (listcount  == index+1)
                {
                    DataTable curTable = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedVoucher"];
                    curTable.Rows[index].Delete();
                    ViewState.Add("SelectedVoucher", curTable);
                    lvSelectedVoucher.DataSource = null;
                    lvSelectedVoucher.DataSource = curTable;
                    lvSelectedVoucher.DataBind();
                    UpdatePanel1.Update();
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something seems logically incorrect here.

Are you always deleting the last Item of ListView ? you are comparing the Index of item to be deleted with the last item actually in the two lines :

```
int listcount = lvSelectedVoucher.Items.Count;
if (listcount - 1 == index)
```

Everything else seems fine, So, did you tried deleting the Last Item of List view and see if it refreshes ?